# Prove that $\forall j,k \in \{1, ..., N\}, \ \forall {n \in \mathbb N}, p^n_{j,k}=\langle T^n e_k,e_j \rangle$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be the probability space. Let $N \in \mathbb{N^*}$ and $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of random variables with values in $\{1, ..., N\}$. Let $\mathcal F_n = \sigma(X_0, ..., X_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ define the associated filtration. We assume the following :

- (A) $\forall {n \in \mathbb N},\ \forall k_0, ..., k_{n+1} \in \{1, ..., N\}$,

$$\mathbb P(X_{n+1}=k_{n+1}|X_n=k_n) = \mathbb P(X_{n+1}=k_{n+1}|\bigcap\limits_{j=0,...,n}(X_j=k_j) )$$

- (B) $\forall j,k \in \{1, ..., N\},\ \forall {n \in \mathbb N}$,

$$ p_{j,k}:=\mathbb P(X_1=k|X_0=j) = \mathbb P(X_{n+1}=k|X_n=j)$$

- (C) $\forall j,k \in \{1, ..., N\}$,

$$ \mathbb P(\exists n \in \mathbb N, X_n=k|X_0=j)=1$$

Let $T=(p_{j,k})_{1≤j,k≤N}, (e_j)^N_{j=1}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^N$. Define $p^n_{j,k}:=\mathbb P(X_n=k|X_0=j)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Prove that $\forall j,k \in \{1, ..., N\},\ \forall n \in \mathbb N$,

$$\ p^n_{j,k}=\langle T^n e_k,e_j \rangle$$

Note: Please do not quote results from the theory of Markov chains directly.

My proof is :

"$(e_j)^N_{j=1}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^N$" means that $(e_j)^N_{j=1}$ is the standard basis (By wiki, Canonical basis refers to the standard basis in a coordinate space and $\mathbb R^N$ is real coordinate space), "$T=(p_{j,k})_{1≤j,k≤N}$" means that "$T^n=p^n_{j,k}$",so we can easily get that $\langle T^n e_k,e_j \rangle =T^n=p^n_{j,k}$ by method of inner product calculation with Euclidean $n$-space.

Actually, I believe that this proof is too simple (maybe it's not right at all) and there must be something missing in this proof (I even do not use any given information about conditional probability as I do not know how to use this information). Does anyone know how to improve this proof? Thank you so much!

Comment: The notation $p_{j,k}^n$ as you defined it does admit of this interpretation (the entries of matrix $T^n$), but it is somewhat misleading as similar to the expression $(p_{j,k})^n$ which does not admit that interpretation.  Once the notation is accepted however, the proof you want can be sketched much as you've done it.

Comment: What is the difference between $(p_{j,k})^n$ and $p^n_{j,k}$ ?

Comment: Suppose that $T=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, so $p_{j,k}$ is $0$ when $j=k$, otherwise $1$.  But the entries of $T^2$ are not the squares of the entries of $T$ (that would mean $T^2=T$ if you do the arithmetic).  So its better to pick a notation that does not suggest the entries of $T^n$ are the $n$th powers of the entries of $T$.  That's not how powers of matrix $T$ are computed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your (A),(B) and (C), is Markov chain, and $T$ is the transition matrix, note distribution $\mu$ transition is $\mu T$, hence $p_{j,k}^n= e_j'T^n e_k= \langle T^ne_k,e_j\rangle$.